# Golang OOP architecture, passing a slice into a constructor, creating a slice object

Tags: oop, go

I just started with `go` language, everything looks cool, I coded everything I need but I have two problems, actually it is passing an slice into a `Struct` or so called `object`, and how to create a method that I can add for example another matrix, but this is minor problem I think.

#### Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    a := Matrix(nonsingularRandomMatrix())
    fmt.Println(a)
}

type Matrix struct {

    inputMatrix [][]int
}

func NewThing(inMatrix [][]int) *Matrix {
    p := new(Matrix)
    p.inputMatrix = inMatrix
    return p
}

func nonsingularRandomMatrix() [][]int {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano())
    var matrixDeterminant int = 0
    nm := make([][]int, 4)
    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        nm[i] = make([]int, 4)
        for j := 0; j < 4; j++ {
            nm[i][j] = rand.Intn(100)
    }
}
matrixDeterminant =
    nm[0][0]*nm[1][1]*nm[2][2]*nm[3][3] - nm[0][0]*nm[1][1]*nm[2][3]*nm[3][2] -
        nm[0][0]*nm[1][2]*nm[2][1]*nm[3][3] + nm[0][0]*nm[1][2]*nm[2][3]*nm[3][1] +
        nm[0][0]*nm[1][3]*nm[2][1]*nm[3][2] - nm[0][0]*nm[1][3]*nm[2][2]*nm[3][1] -
        nm[0][1]*nm[1][0]*nm[2][2]*nm[3][3] + nm[0][1]*nm[1][0]*nm[2][3]*nm[3][2] +
        nm[0][1]*nm[1][2]*nm[2][0]*nm[3][3] - nm[0][1]*nm[1][2]*nm[2][3]*nm[3][0] -
        nm[0][1]*nm[1][3]*nm[2][0]*nm[3][2] + nm[0][1]*nm[1][3]*nm[2][2]*nm[3][0] +
        nm[0][2]*nm[1][0]*nm[2][1]*nm[3][3] - nm[0][2]*nm[1][0]*nm[2][3]*nm[3][1] -
        nm[0][2]*nm[1][1]*nm[2][0]*nm[3][3] + nm[0][2]*nm[1][1]*nm[2][3]*nm[3][0] +
        nm[0][2]*nm[1][3]*nm[2][0]*nm[3][1] - nm[0][2]*nm[1][3]*nm[2][1]*nm[3][0] -
        nm[0][3]*nm[1][0]*nm[2][1]*nm[3][2] + nm[0][3]*nm[1][0]*nm[2][2]*nm[3][1] +
        nm[0][3]*nm[1][1]*nm[2][0]*nm[3][2] - nm[0][3]*nm[1][1]*nm[2][2]*nm[3][0] -
        nm[0][3]*nm[1][2]*nm[2][0]*nm[3][1] + nm[0][3]*nm[1][2]*nm[2][1]*nm[3][0]
if matrixDeterminant == 0 {
    nonsingularRandomMatrix()
}
return nm
}
```

#### Output from my console:

> go run oop.go
>
> command-line-arguments
>
> .\oop.go:10: cannot convert nonsingularRandomMatrix() (type [][]int) to type Matrix

Any clue?

Greets!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your compiler is saying is that `[][]int` and `Matrix` are two totally unrelated types. You can not convert from one to the other. Thats because `Matrix` is a `struct` which *contains* a `[][]int`, but `Matrix` *is not* an `[][]int`. To create a `Matrix` out of it you'd need to create a new `Matrix` and set the `[][]int` to the only member:

```
a := Matrix{nonsingularRandomMatrix()}
```

An easier way would be if `Matrix` *were* a `[][]int`.

```
type Matrix [][]int
```

This would just create a new name (`Matrix`) for `[][]int`, and in this case, a simple (explicit) conversion would work

```
Matrix(nonsingularRandomMatrix())
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It saved me a lot of effort, but now it generates me another question, how i can refer to current Object, for example i have some Matrix object with some values, and i want to add another Matrix, so how i can refer inside method as self.Matrix or sth like that ?

Comment: Okay, got it! Ill post code if anyone will need some feedback on this ;)

    type MatrixMethods interface {
        add(inputMatrix [][]int) [][]int
    }
    
    type Matrix [][]int

    func NewThing(inMatrix [][]int) *Matrix {
         p := new(Matrix)
     return p
    }

    func (m Matrix) add(inputMatrix [][]int) {
     fmt.Println("Matrix 1", m)
     fmt.Println("Another Matrix", inputMatrix)
     // do what you want! :)

     }